# Type definition in object literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript classes it's possible to declare types for properties, for example:

```
class className {
  property: string;
};
```

How do declare the type of a property in an object literal?

I've tried the following code but it doesn't compile:

```
var obj = {
  property: string;
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The name 'string' does not exist in the current scope

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 641, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to replace the `=` with a `:`. You can use an object type literal (see spec section 3.5.3) or an interface. Using an object type literal is close to what you have:

```
var obj: { property: string; } = { property: "foo" };
```

But you can also use an interface

```
interface MyObjLayout {
    property: string;
}

var obj: MyObjLayout = { property: "foo" };
```

Comment: The DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) option by @Rick Love with the cast operator seems mucho neater. Just commenting, not downvoting...

Comment: I know this has been answered a while ago, but am I mistaken in the assumptions that issues can arise when the class has methods as well as properties? Since the class doesn't get initialized and we only assign properties, calling a method on the class will cause a null exception. Basically, the object we create only 'acts' as the class because we assign its type, but it is not actually an instance of that class. I.e. we need to create the class with the 'new' keyword. And we're then back to square 1, since we can't do something like new class() {prop: 1}; in TS like we can in C#, for example.

Comment: @DeuxAlpha This is assigning to an _interface_, which can't have methods. I don't believe that you can assign to a class like this.

Comment: link to spec would be nice :)

Comment: @DeuxAlpha this is creating an object literal, not an class object. Also an interface can have methods. If your interface defines a method, then the object literal must also define it - it won't be null. The object literal must fulfill everything the the interface defines or the type system will show an error.

Comment: For a simpler DRY alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942500/523014

Comment: @spechter: Using the cast operator means you lose some type-safety, so that would be strictly worse.

Comment: @JacquesB - Yeah I totally get that. But in my mind, simpler clearer code sometimes wins out over the most correct code (surely a religious debate though). Depends how likely things are to 'go wrong' which will vary by context...

Answer (score 367):

#### Update 2019-05-15 (Improved Code Pattern as Alternative)

After many years of using `const` and benefiting from more functional code, I would recommend against using my original answers in most cases (the headings below this section i.e. when building objects, forcing the type system into a specific type instead of letting it infer types is often an indication that something is wrong).

Instead I would recommend using `const` variables as much as possible and then compose the object as the final step:

```
const id = getId();
const hasStarted = true;
...
const hasFinished = false;
...
return { hasStarted, hasFinished, id };
```

- This will properly type everything without any need for explicit typing.
- There is no need to retype the field types.
- This leads to the cleanest code from my experience.
- This allows the compiler to provide more state verification (for example, if you return in multiple locations, the compiler will ensure the same type of object is always returned - which encourages you to declare the whole return value at each position - giving a perfectly clear intention of that value).

#### Bonus: Optional Fields 2022-09-29

```
const id = getId();
const optionalField = getOptionalValue();
return {
    id,
    // This will always exist as a key in the object but it might be undefined
    optionalField,
    // This will only exist as a key in the object if it has a truthy value
    ...optionalField2 ? { optionalField } : {},
    // This will only exist as a key in the object if it is not null or undefined
    ...optionalField2 != null ? { optionalField } : {},
};
```

#### Addition 2020-02-26

If you do actually need a type that you can be lazily initialized: Mark it is a nullable union type (null or Type). The type system will prevent you from using it without first ensuring it has a value.

In `tsconfig.json`, make sure you enable strict null checks:

`"strictNullChecks": true`

Then use this pattern and allow the type system to protect you from accidental null/undefined access:

```
const state = {
    instance: null as null | ApiService,
    // OR
    // instance: undefined as undefined | ApiService,

};

const useApi = () => {
    // If I try to use it here, the type system requires a safe way to access it

    // Simple lazy-initialization 
    const api = state?.instance ?? (state.instance = new ApiService());
    api.fun();

    // Also here are some ways to only access it if it has value:

    // The 'right' way: Typescript 3.7 required
    state.instance?.fun();

    // Or the old way: If you are stuck before Typescript 3.7
    state.instance && state.instance.fun();

    // Or the long winded way because the above just feels weird
    if (state.instance) { state.instance.fun(); }

    // Or the I came from C and can't check for nulls like they are booleans way
    if (state.instance != null) { state.instance.fun(); }

    // Or the I came from C and can't check for nulls like they are booleans 
    // AND I was told to always use triple === in javascript even with null checks way
    if (state.instance !== null && state.instance !== undefined) { state.instance.fun(); }
};

class ApiService {
    fun() {
        // Do something useful here
    }
}
```

---

#### Do not do the below in 99% of cases:

#### Update 2016-02-10 - To Handle TSX (Thanks @Josh)

Use the `as` operator for TSX.

```
var obj = {
    property: null as string
};
```

A longer example:

```
var call = {
    hasStarted: null as boolean,
    hasFinished: null as boolean,
    id: null as number,
};
```

#### Original Answer

Use the cast operator to make this succinct (by casting null to the desired type).

```
var obj = {
    property: <string> null
};
```

A longer example:

```
var call = {
    hasStarted: <boolean> null,
    hasFinished: <boolean> null,
    id: <number> null,
};
```

This is much better than having two parts (one to declare types, the second to declare defaults):

```
var callVerbose: {
    hasStarted: boolean;
    hasFinished: boolean;
    id: number;
} = {
    hasStarted: null,
    hasFinished: null,
    id: null,
};
```

Comment: If you are using TSX (TS with JSX), you cannot use the angle bracket naming, so those lines become something like `property: null as string` wherein the important difference is the `as` operator.

Comment: @RickLove Does this actually constrain the type of the object variable, or is this only a way to specify the types when assigned? In other words, after you assign to the variable `call` in your second example, can you assign a completely different type to it?

Comment: This defines the type of variable just as if it were explicitly defined. The code has identical affect in the type system.

Comment: This should be answer

Comment: not working. `Error:(33, 15) TS2352:Type 'null' cannot be converted to type 'string'.`

Comment: @novaline It sounds like you have strict null checks enabled. You might try ```null as string | null```

Comment: Is this just an abuse of a feature of the language or is this actually Legit? Could you provide link for mor reading to oficial docs? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this is not friendly with React at all https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23088

Comment: @Qwerty This question and answer is about object literals and not classes. If you are using a generic base class (like the link does), you must define the specific types for the base class. That has nothing to do with React, but is concerning inheritance of generic base classes. For React, if you want implicit typing, you should use pure function components when possible. If you really need a stateful component, you simply must declare the state type in the inheritance declaration.

Comment: But it will not have type checking?

Comment: Is the code you have with the angle brackets called type assertion? (property: <string> null ) I'm reading the typescript documents and it mentions it on this page. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @RickLove Regarding your 2019 update, do you want to revise it in light of the new TypeScript 3.4 const assertions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html , `let z = { text: "hello" } as const;` ? Also, could you give a more explicit example of your 2019 update? THANKS.

Comment: @Sumomo A _const declaration_ is a ES supported feature that prevents the variable from being modified (however the contents of that object could still be modified, so it's basically a constant reference to the object). The new typescript _const assertion_ is a typescript only supported feature that tells the compiler to treat the contents of the object as constant values (and most specific type). In the above case, it might make sense to use both. (Also note, that _const assertions_ do not guarantee immutability, i.e. arrays could still be changed, etc.)

Comment: Correction: _const assertions_ only guarantee immutability for the items declared as part of the object literal. For example, an array or object that was declared before the object literal and then is placed in the object literal as a variable will only be a constant reference. The object/array itself is still mutable since it was declared outside the const context.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, a perfect solution, for a quick object inside a class. Defining an interface is usefull when i am planning to re-use that structure again. but there are times, when i want a n object only at one place, but also want to take benefits of typescript.

Comment: @RickLove aren't you making the global namespace a mess with all these const everywhere? I personally like to have a single const object/namespace for my app, and then put everything inside. Although I agree that having const properties would be nice

Comment: @LidelnKyoku these are not like `const` from other languages. These are scoped to the current block, just like a `let`. Both `let` and `const` are block scoped which is tighter than `var` which is function scoped and should no longer be used.

Comment: @LidelnKyoku Note: I see that javascript used to have another `const` before es6 that was supported in some browsers. So I'm not talking about the old way it worked before ECMAScript 6, but as it works after es6.

Comment: @RickLove we could indeed use an IIFE for scoping purposes. So in your experience, you reckon that defining all these const beforehand and only adding them to an object/namespace after is safer and not that time-consuming? If so, then I should try, even though I think it's not everyday that I accidentally redefine an existing object/namespace method. But better safe than sorry...

Comment: @LidelnKyoku The IIFE pattern is obsolete. It has have been replaced by modules and block scope among other things. You should read up on ECMAscript modules. Here is a blog article that might help: https://tylermcginnis.com/javascript-modules-iifes-commonjs-esmodules/

Comment: @RickLove yeaaaah well, I'm not so fond of this feature, TBH. I find some JS features to be more of a hurdle. Like they say: if it ain't broken, don't fix it :) Not fond of classes either. They try to mimic class-based languages, but it doesn't feel "right". But hey, to each his own, right? :) Thanks anyway Rick!

Comment: `The above creates a mutable object that will have it's field set throughout the function instead of all at once`, you could just use `Object.freeze(call);`, known as a shallow freeze.

Comment: @Karl, what I meant was that the object was being mutated throughout the function with a false type about it at the beginning. It is faking out the type system instead of allowing the type system to catch mistakes. Using consts is ideal because it allows the type system to help you. This is all about type time (coding time) and not about run-time mutability.

Comment: Love the comment for typescript 3.7, as I was unaware of the '?.' operator and could not find any other reference anywhere. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: great! i upvoted. but would like to know, how would you do getters and setters in this context?

Comment: @RickLove Why do you say: **Do not do the below in 99% of cases**?

Comment: This post only makes sense when read from the bottom to the top! The first sentence says, "I would recommend against using the below..." and then the very second sentence makes a recommendation. Which recommendation am I supposed to ignore?

Comment: Defining properties as the final step doesn't work for me because I have optional properties and doing `return {x: x ? x : undefined}` isn't the same as not setting `x` at all. I also care about the order the properties are defined in because I serialize the object as JSON and display it to users (my users are developers).

Comment: @Zoman because typescript has changed and const is better

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy  I added optional fields

Comment: While this is nice, you are literally retyping the field names in the return object...
so this point is not valid `There is no need to retype the field names.`

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis good catch, meant to say `field types`

Comment: doesnt work when use as a function arg eg: `function funcn ({hasStarted: null as boolean, hasFinished: null as boolean, id: null as number}) {  }`

Comment: @Nor.Z function fun(args = {hasStarted: undefined as undefined | boolean}){}, but there are much better ways to do this as a parameter

Answer (score 99):

I'm surprised that no-one's mentioned this but you could just create an interface called `ObjectLiteral`, that accepts `key: value` pairs of type `string: any`:

```
interface ObjectLiteral {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Then you'd use it, like this:

```
let data: ObjectLiteral = {
  hello: "world",
  goodbye: 1,
  // ...
};
```

An added bonus is that you can re-use this interface many times as you need, on as many objects you'd like.

Good luck.

Comment: This is a bad idea, it makes the type system worthless. The point of typescript is to allow the type system to help prevent errors and also to help provide better autocomplete functionality in tooling - this basically disables all the benefits of Typescript. It would be better to not use any interface in the above example.

Comment: @RickLove I strongly disagree. This has been exceptionally useful when several properties are optional but we still want to clearly define all types within (e.g. containing arguments for a function). This could be simply viewed as syntactic sugar and literally works like a **[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for Interfaces' properties**.

Comment: @CPHPython why not just specify the optional parameters with their specific types? The only time this would make sense is if the names are not known at code time (I.e. they are coming from a database or external source). Also for complex combinations of arguments, union types work great. If you are coding against specific names, they should be defined if possible. If it is just data that doesn’t affect logic, then of course leave it out from the type system.

Comment: @RickLove "the names are not known at code time" -> this is a good and practical example, the values of those keys types are known and they are all the same (e.g. _string_). Mind that I was only advocating the use  of the `[key: string]` part, not the _any_ part as the value's type definition... That'd indeed take out the types usefulness.

Comment: How would I go about if I want to allow string and numbers to be added but not other types?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana You'd use `[key: string]: string | number;`.

Comment: Typing as `Record<string, unknown>` also works perfectly.

Answer (score 62):

You could use predefined utility type [**`Record<Keys, Type>`**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) :

```
const obj: Record<string, string> = {
  property: "value",
};
```

It allows to specify keys for your object literal:

```
type Keys = "prop1" | "prop2"

const obj: Record<Keys, string> = {
  prop1: "Hello",
  prop2: "Aloha",
  something: "anything" // TS Error: Type '{ prop1: string; prop2: string; something: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<Keys, string>'.
                        //   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'something' does not exist in type 'Record<Keys, string>'.
};
```

And a type for the property value:

```
type Keys = "prop1" | "prop2"
type Value = "Hello" | "Aloha"

const obj1: Record<Keys, Value> = {
  prop1: "Hello",
  prop2: "Hey", // TS Error: Type '"Hey"' is not assignable to type 'Value'.
};
```

Comment: I'd also use `let` instead of `var` here.

Comment: if you have a dynamic type, use this.

Answer (score 26):

If you're trying to write a type annotation, the syntax is:

```
var x: { property: string; } = { property: 'hello' };
```

If you're trying to write an object literal, the syntax is:

```
var x = { property: 'hello' };
```

Your code is trying to use a type name in a value position.

Answer (score 16):

If you're trying to add typings to a *destructured* object literal, for example in arguments to a function, the syntax is:

```
function foo({ bar, baz }: { bar: boolean, baz: string }) {
  // ...
}

foo({ bar: true, baz: 'lorem ipsum' });
```

Answer (score 10):

In TypeScript if we are declaring object then we'd use the following syntax:

```
[access modifier] variable name : { /* structure of object */ }
```

For example:

```
private Object:{ Key1: string, Key2: number }
```

Answer (score 8):

Beware. It may seem obvious to some, but the type declaration:

```js
const foo: TypeName = {}
```

is not the same compared to casting with `as`:

```js
const foo = {} as TypeName
```

despite the suggestions to use it on other answers.

Example:

Thanks, type-safety!:

```
const foo: { [K in 'open' | 'closed']: string } = {}
// ERROR: TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ open: string; closed: string; }': open, closed
```

Goodbye, type-safety!:

```
const foo = {} as { [K in 'open' | 'closed']: string }
// No error
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what I'm doing in 2021 with TypeScript 4.5:

```
const sm = {
  reg: {} as ServiceWorkerRegistration,
  quantum: null as number | null,
  currentCacheName: '' as string, // superfluous
  badSWTimer: 0 as number, // superfluous
}
```

This is not just a value cast, but works the same as an interface definition, for the object properties that is.

Update: I included two superfluous typings as an example. That is, these typings can be inferred automatically and thus, would not generate compiler errors.

Source: [4.4 Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBBC2MC8MDeAoGMBOBTA5gFxoC+MAhhDAMq7YBuAlsLgOojYDWdASgY9GzkojcABpMMAI4BXcmCgz4xMDIA2ailVXwARnRgAfGKo0SswGdjwKAwuWAALXADly8XMQDkXrXCjYjGD4YjAA9GFwMgAOdABmajIgMhCSuuQAJtSsACqMHtjEAAx+OvrYoRFRsdgJSSnoJOjoVQgAdLLyiogoXhm4cUGMULhqAJ4UMABEZXRToWMxbVO+VTmO2CAA7lTkMFBjsTB0m9jooJAgarhtaiD4ABQIAJRAA)

Comment: Could you link a TS 4.5 reference please? (Especially for "not just a value cast" part.)

Comment: @JanMolnar Much obliged... see Source link

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I do not see a difference between the mentioned TS 4.5, linked 4.4 and e.g. the old 3.3, so I do not know what is the thing which is new in 2021. Maybe "new since 2012" was meant, not specifically in 2021.

Comment: I don't think you should ever really use `as`

Comment: This absolutely does not work that same as an interface definition. If ServiceWorkerRegistration has an object in it, this will not warn you. You're telling typescript "Even though this empty object is not a ServiceWorkerRegistration, pretend it is!". So when you call `sm.reg.item.value`, you'll get an error.

Comment: @RayFoss 1. open your Playground 2. add `console.log(sm.reg.pushManager.getSubscription)` 3. look at the error TS didn't warn you about because of `as`. 4. Add interface 5. See TS warn you of error

Answer (score 6):

```
// Use ..

const Per = {
  name: 'HAMZA',
  age: 20,
  coords: {
    tele: '09',
    lan: '190'
  },
  setAge(age: Number): void {
    this.age = age;
  },
  getAge(): Number {
    return age;
  }
};
const { age, name }: { age: Number; name: String } = Per;
const {
  coords: { tele, lan }
}: { coords: { tele: String; lan: String } } = Per;

console.log(Per.getAge());
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Can you expand your answer at all, it would be helpful to explain how/why this works.

Answer (score 5):

In your code:

```
var obj = {
  myProp: string;
};
```

You are actually creating a object literal and assigning the variable string to the property myProp. Although very bad practice this would actually be valid TS code (don't use this!):

```
var string = 'A string';

var obj = {
  property: string
};
```

---

However, what you want is that the object literal is typed. This can be achieved in various ways:

**Interface:**

```
interface myObj {
    property: string;
}

var obj: myObj = { property: "My string" };
```

**Type alias:**

```
type myObjType = {
    property: string
};

var obj: myObjType = { property: "My string" };
```

**Object type literal:**

```
var obj: { property: string; } = { property: "Mystring" };
```

Answer (score 5):

As of TypeScript 4.9, the [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) can be used to make inline assertions. You can use it for one value or the entire object like so:

```
interface NameInfo {
  first: string;
  last: string | undefined;
}
const people = {
  john: { first: "John", last: "Doe" },
  jane: { first: "Jane", last: "Doe" } satisfies NameInfo,
} satisfies Record<string, NameInfo>;
```

Another option is to create a class with static properties:

```
class TestData {
  static people: Record<string, NameInfo> = {
    john: { first: "John", last: "Doe" },
    jane: { first: "Jane", last: "Doe" },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. create a type using type keyword

```js
type ObjType = {
  property: string;
}
```

and then you can use it to bind your object to accept this type only, like below.

```
const obj: ObjType = {
property: "TypeScript"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend @RickLove's reply...

This works great, as you only need to define the type that cannot be inferred:

```js
const initialState = { 
   user: undefined as User | undefined, 
   userLoading: false
};
```

and it transpiles to this js code:

```js
const initialState = { 
   user: undefined, 
   userLoading: false
};
```

And if you need to extract it into a type, you can just do this:

```js
export type InitState = typeof initialState;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Convert Object Literal into Type With DRY**

Just do:

```js
const myObject = {
   hello: 'how are you',
   hey: 'i am fine thank you'
}
```

```js
type myObjectType = keyof typeof MyObject
```

Job done!