# TypeScript Duck Typing, not showing error on property string into number

Tags: typescript

**Not Duplicate**

This is not the duplicate question because here my issue is in index signature not in object literal or type annotation. Please read carefully my question.

In few days I started to learn TypeScript. While when I reached at topic duck typing. I am confused in some of its basic rules.

**Overview**

In below code I have complete understanding. That, why we are using duck typing.

```
//Object declaration & initialization
let obj1 : {id:number, name:string};
obj1 = {id: 1,name: "Ahmer Ali Ahsan"};
//Error, missing property name
obj1 = {id:1};

let obj2 : {id:number, [obj2: string]:any};
obj2 = {id: 1, firstname: "Ahmer"};
//We add new property members due to index signatures
obj2 = {id: 2, firstname: "Ahmer", middlename:"Ali", lastname: "Ahsan"};
//We erase property members due to index signatures
obj2 = {id:2};
```

**Problem**

I have a question that if TypeScript is a type safety language. Then in below code I have all parameter types are number and index signature type is also a number.

```
let obj3 : {id:number, [obj3: number]: number};
obj3 = {id: 1, rollno: "Why error is not showing here?"};
```

**Question**

Why is there no error due to the `[obj: number]: number` index signature when I assign `rollno` to a string value?

Please explain briefly with your answers. If my concepts of index signature is still not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type definition in object literal in TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript)

Comment: @Sheepy this is not a duplicate question because I am not taking about type annotation or object literal. My issue is related to index signature. Please ready carefully my question and complete detail of it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation: All keys of this object must be numeric, and all values must be of type `number`

Actual interpretation: All values reached by numeric keys must be of type `number`

Consider `Array<boolean>`. It has a numeric index signature to type `boolean` because e.g. accessing `arr[0]` produces a value of type `boolean`. But `arr.toString` (a key which is a `string` type) has type `() => string`, which is clearly not the same as `boolean`.

---

Edit to add based on comments.

Let's consider a declaration:

```
var x: { [n: number]: boolean; };
```

This is a numeric index signature. A numeric index signature says that properties with numeric names match a particular type. They have no effect on properties with non-numeric names.

*Numeric index signatures only constrain properties with numeric names (not string names)*

### Numeric index signatures only constrain properties with numeric names  (not string names)

## *Numeric index signatures only constrain properties with numeric names  (not string names)*

In other words, these are OK, because their key names are not numeric:

```
x = { hello: 100 }; // OK! 'hello' is not numeric
x = { rollno: 'wat!'}; // OK! 'rollno' is not numeric
x = { lookThisIsNotNumeric: false }; // OK! 'lookThisIsNotNumeric' is not numeric
```

Conversely, these are *not* OK, because the numeric-named properties do not fit the index signature type:

```
x = { 1: 'hello' }; // Error! 1 is a number and 'hello' is not a boolean
x = { 10: 653 }; // Error! 10 is a number and 653 is not a boolean
x = { 25: 'hello' }; // Error! 25 is a number and 'hello' is not a boolean
```

Finally, this *is* OK, because the numeric-named property has a boolean value:

```
x = { 42: true };
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But its easy to me for understand. If you reference my index signature example in your answer.

Comment: In my example parameter rollno has type number but in below line I put string instead of number. Why its not showing me an error?

Comment: `rollno` is not a number, it's a string. string-keyed values are not subject to the constraints of the numeric index signature because you can't seen through a numeric key.

Comment: In other words, if a sign on a door said "All people wearing hats must be wearing shoes" and someone came through the door with *no hat* and *no shoes*, that's not a violation of the sign. Same here, the rule implied by the index signature is "All properties with numeric keys must be numbers".

Comment: I understand your last comment but not understand your second last comment. If my rollno is not a number then in my index signature why I am using type number `[obj3: number]`. Please clear my miss understanding.

Comment: Added a bunch of examples. I cannot clarify further.

Comment: Finally this is the answer.Which I was looking for. Thanks for your precious time.