# How to use a tuple in a class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn TypeScript (2.1) by creating a dice roller. I figured I'd use tuples to match up the side rolled with a picture. For example, if I roll a 1 (using a random number generator I plan on implementing), I get back the representation for a circle.

```
class D6 {
    values: [number, string];
    values = [1, "Circle"];
}
```

However, just with that little bit of code, I am getting this error:

`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'values' must be of type '[number, string]', but here has type '(string | number)[]'.`

Is it possible to use tuples in a class in TypeScript?

Comment: You probably want to use something closer to an object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
class D6 {
    values: [number, string] = [1, "Circle"];
}
```

In your code you are defining two properties with the same name (`values`).