# Specifying the type of the value in an object literal in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

This is a different question than the one at [Type definition in object literal in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript)

I have an interface that accepts any object as one of its properties:

```
interface MyType {
  /* ... */
  options: any;
}
```

While the property `options` can be anything, sometimes I want to specify certain types. I don't want to use the 'as' keyword because I don't want to coerce it (I want to see errors if I'm missing a property).

Here's one way I can do it:

```
interface MyTypeOptions {
  hasName: boolean;
  hasValue: boolean;
}

// Declare the options separately just so we can specify a type
const options: MyTypeOptions = {
  hasName: false,
  hasValue: true
};

const myType: MyType = {
  /* ... */
  options
}
```

But is there a way to do it while keeping the options inline inside the `myType` object literal, without using type assertion? In other words, I want to do this:

```
const myType: MyType = {
  /* ... */
  // I want to type-check that the following value is of type MyTypeOptions
  options: {
    hasName: false,
    hasValue: true
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for generics. You can make `MyType` generic and specify `MyTypeOptions`as a type parameter to `MyType`

```
interface MyTypeOptions {
    hasName: boolean;
    hasValue: boolean;
}

// Declare the options separately just so we can specify a type
const options: MyTypeOptions = {
    hasName: false,
    hasValue: true
}

// We specify any as the default to T so we can also use MyType without a type parameter
interface MyType<T = any> {
    /* ... */
    options: T;
}
const myType: MyType<MyTypeOptions> = {
    options: {
        hasName: false,
        hasValue: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of TypeScript 4.9 you can use the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
interface MyTypeOptions {
  hasName: boolean;
  hasValue: boolean;
}

const myType: MyType = {
  options: {
    hasName: false,
    hasValue: true
  } satisfies MyTypeOptions // Checks the type without casting it
}
```

Comment: `myType.options` still has the type `any`

Comment: @zenly OP specifically mentioned they did not want to coerce the type. If you'd like to coerce/cast the object, use `as`.

Comment: Okay, I know that. I'm just pointing out something that may not be immediately obvious. The currently accepted answer does not have this behavior.