# How to specify type of an arrow function defined as an object literal in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue-router

I have the following object:

```
  let route = {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.state.system.loggedIn) {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    },
  }
```

This specifies a route object for Vue Router. The problem is with function `beforeEnter`, as I get a TS7006 error - all parameters implicitly have `any` type.

I could specify the parameter types by hand, but there already exists the exact type the `beforeEnter` function is supposed to fit - it's called `NavigationGuard`, and I can import it from `vue-router` just fine.

The problem comes when I try to specify it, I can't seem to find the right syntax. I found the question "[Type definition in object literal in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript)" where an answer suggests either specifying the type of the entire object, or casting it like so: `{ hasStarted: <boolean> null, ... }` but replacing the definition with

```
let route = {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: <NavigationGuard> (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.state.system.loggedIn) {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    },
  }
```

doesn't seem to appease the compiler.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the confusion with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), you need parenthesis:

```
<NavigationGuard>((to, from, next) => {
  // …
})
```

Or:

```
((to, from, next) => {
  // …
}) as NavigationGuard
```

But you should be able to use typing on the parent object:

```
let route: RouteConfig = {
  path: "/login",
  name: "login",
  component: Login,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.state.system.loggedIn) {
      next("/");
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
}
```