# Object initialization - why are object attributes initialized with " : " not " = "

Tags: javascript

Been going through Angular tutorials and realized that : is used for type declarations, while = is used for value assignment. Looking at the following code

```js
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  }
```

I don't understand why id and name are using : as opposed to = since the type was already declared and we are assigning a value to the attributes of hero.

```js
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero = {
    id = 1,
    name = 'Windstorm'
  }
```

Above is code that I would expect to work but is incorrect.

Comment: This is javascript syntax for defining objects

Comment: That syntax is javascript specific, it has nothing to do directly with angular or typescript. I updated your question tag accordingly.

Comment: Also this what you expect would suggest we are in some kind of function body and would be confusing for larger objects

Comment: Yes, it's inconsistent, due to JS object literals being far older than type annotations (which [don't really support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787781/1048572) type annotations on their values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can be initialized using different methods in JavaScript. One method you are probably more familiar with is by first creating an instance of an object and assign properties through the constructors, getters and setters, or by directly mutating the object property

```
// Creates a hero object with no properties
let hero = new Hero();

// Creates a hero object with defined properties
let hero = new Hero(1, 'Windstorm');

// Creates a hero object then sets the object property
let hero = new Hero();
hero.id = 1;
hero.name = 'Windstorm';
```

While these methods of creating objects in JavaScript are valid, you will most often see developers use Object Literals, which is a list of name-value pairs, separated by commas. You may have noticed, but JSON adopts the same syntax that Object Literals use, with one difference in being language-independent (Object Literals are unique to JavaScript). To extend my explanation a bit, you can assign any data type to object literal property values: it can be an array, a string, an integer, ANOTHER OBJECT LITERAL, etc. all at the simple press of the ":" on your keyboard.

Hopefully I was able to help, best of luck!

Comment: Actually, the constructor call with `new` doesn't create any properties, the code you've shown might do anything. The property creation happens explicitly inside the constructor body code, again by boring old assignment.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, I haven't mentioned that you had to first write your Hero class with a constructor for setting the object's id and name. Thanks for the correction!