# How to declare an object whose properties are of type string only using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I have a configuration array in my component like this.

```
...
config: ButtonConfig[];
...
this.config.push(new ButtonConfig(...));
...
```

Today, I realized that it makes more sense to have the array behave like a dictionary so I can access the particular elements not by a numeric index but rather canonically by a name. I want to be able to do `config.submitButton` and not `config[3]` (even if I have an enum declared that maps *submitButton* to the requested index).

```
...
config = { };
...
this.config.submitButton = new ButtonConfig(...);
...
```

This works but I'm now allowing a bunch of `any`'s to spoof my code base, which is bad. I want the object to be aware that only things of type `ButtonConfig` can be put into it.

I can declare a class with the fields because I want the number of them to be dynamically addable in the future, so the following won't do.

```
export class ButtonConfigs {
  submitConfig: ButtonConfig, ...
}
```

I've check [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript) not really recognizing what I'm looking for. Is it possible at all or an I confusing myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple answer is this:

```
export type ButtonConfigs = {
  [key: string]: ButtonConfig;
}
```

This works very well, if you want a high level of dynamics.

If you want to lock it down a little, you could define an enum that contains the possible keys you want to allow:

```
export enum ButtonConfigKeys {
  'submitConfig',
  'someOtherKey',
  '...'
}

export type ButtonConfigs = {
  [key: ButtonConfigKeys]: ButtonConfig;
}
```

Comment: Perfect reply. Accepted as the correct answer. And +1 for the totally unsolicited extra info that actually resolved another issue I was going to have soon. Good sniper skills, mate.

Comment: Would you say that your approach is to be preferred before using interfaces?

Comment: You mean using `type` over `interface`? I think that's a personal preference. My team has agreed to use `type` over `interface` merely beacuse of the semantics on the words.

Comment: @Got ya, thanks. I got curious and [couldn't resist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818032/why-would-interface-or-type-be-preferred-if-anything-in-typescript-under-speci) nerding it down in a separate thread. Just letting you know that I'm not criticizing your semantics based choice. I'm just curious on the broader plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following:

```
config: { [key:string]: ButtonConfig } = {};

...
this.config.submitButton = new ButtonConfig(...);
...
```

Here's a working stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opc8yg

Answer (score 0):

```
const btn: {[keys: string]: string} = {
    key: 'value',
    anotherKey: 'anotherValue'
}
```

This example should help you.