# Interface whose properties are of types A and B only in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, complex-data-types

I've created a holder for my configs with type `ButtonConfigs` like this (as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787976/8744999)).

```
export interface ButtonConfigs {
  [key: string]: ButtonConfig;
}
```

The I continued with other components' configs as well so that every type has its own config property in the component.

```
...
buttonConfigs: ButtonConfigs = {};
folderConfigs: FolderConfigs = {};
txtBoxConfigs: TxtBoxConfigs = {};
...
```

Then it hit me that I should be able to aggregate all the configs to a common property. It really makes sense in my case, too.

However, I'm not sure if I can change the interface in such a way that it allows for different types, still restricting the contents of the `configs` not to be `any`. My current approach is poorly designed.

```
export interface Configs {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

How can I tell TypeScript that the type of the field should be `TextBoxConfig`, `ButtonConfig` or `FolderConfig` but nothing else?

Comment: `[key: string]: ButtonConfig | TxtBoxConfig | FolderConfig ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)?

```js
interface ButtonConfig {
  a: string;
}
interface FolderConfigs {
  b: number;
}
interface TxtBoxConfigs {
  c: boolean;
}

export interface Configs {
  [key: string]: ButtonConfig | FolderConfigs | TxtBoxConfigs;
}

const config: Configs = {
  buttonConfig: {
    a: "testing"
  },
  folderConfig: {
    b: 1 
  },
  textConfig: {
    c: true 
  },
  anotherConfig: { // error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    a: 1
  },
  moreConfig: {
    d: "test" // error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'd' does not exist in type 'ButtonConfig | FolderConfigs | TxtBoxConfigs'.
  }
}
```

[Here is the playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcxgPYgMK4zADmyA3gFDLJwBcyAzmFKMQNwUC+FoksiKAGLYANgBNoBEEWINyVZACN6IdAFtF0Dt17R4SZABUAHmFTZjUmXMrUE9RdlEQ4IbRQoRjAB2xQwyLr8BlYkNgoA2gDWEACe9EwsIMQAuvQYWLihpAA+yMLikoRhyHkmZhbZDO4UCLhMyHXSJPRVyAC88tSKmDj4xcT0ttQ09ABEkEysYwqcADQKMKISUNlDCt30AIzIswvUkKZrXSP2yMzoKHsKrthgABZFzYPkyAD0b8jQUH70hrHeFAAclUGmgQMCchAdxoDAYJBAcEUIhQOHOAOBiVYQIAdBtRsgttdqGo-BBjsNqGJxpMwGN3p9vr9kAB5RQAKwgCACImAfDgImQajgsWQuBEooYgIQwBgoqi0IA7iBkN4foD-MAIAw5jQQGJkECxBCxNhtchoQEvMAGqB0YDDRk+tlSvllk9rK7yuZLAMGLjZlwgA)