# How to correctly use an interface on a literal object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm struggling a bit with typescript. Suppose you have a literal object where its value is assigned with the spread operator:

```js
const defaultState = () => {
  return {
    profile: {
      id: '',
      displayName: '',
      givenName: '',
      surName: '',
    },
  }
}

const state = reactive(defaultState())
const response = await getGraphProfile()
state.profile = { ...defaultState().profile, ...response.data }
```

After an update of the types library `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types` the following TS errors is thrown:

```
TS2322: Type '{ accountEnabled?: Maybe<boolean>; ageGroup?: string | null | undefined; assignedLicenses?: MicrosoftGraph.AssignedLicense[] | undefined; assignedPlans?: MicrosoftGraph.AssignedPlan[] | undefined; ... 102 more ...; surName: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; displayName: string; givenName: string; surName: string; jobTitle: string; mail: string; mobilePhone: string; officeLocation: string; businessPhones: string[]; preferredLanguage: string; userPrincipalName: string; }'.
  Types of property 'displayName' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Trying to set the the interface `MicrosoftGraph.User` on the literal object as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript) did not resolve it as I must be doing something wrong with the syntax:

```js
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types'

const defaultState = () => {
  return {
    profile: MicrosoftGraph.User = {
      id: '',
      displayName: '',
      givenName: '',
      surName: '',
    },
  }
}
```

This throws the TS error below but the `User` interface is definitely there and correctly used in the function `getGraphProfile`.

> TS2339: Property 'User' does not exist on type 'typeof import("T:/Test/Brecht/Node/prod/hip-frontend/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/microsoft-graph")'.

**Extra code:**

```js
import config from 'src/app-config.json'
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'
import { getToken } from 'src/services/auth/authService'
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types'

const callGraph = <T>(
  url: string,
  token: string,
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  const params: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
  return axios.request<T>({ ...params, ...axiosConfig })
}

const getGraphDetails = async <T>(
  uri: string,
  scopes: string[],
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  try {
    const response = await getToken(scopes)
    if (response && response.accessToken) {
      return callGraph<T>(uri, response.accessToken, axiosConfig)
    } else {
      throw new Error('We could not get a token because of page redirect')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`We could not get a token: ${error}`)
  }
}

export const getGraphProfile = async () => {
  try {
    return await getGraphDetails<MicrosoftGraph.User>(
      config.resources.msGraphProfile.uri,
      config.resources.msGraphProfile.scopes
    )
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Failed retrieving the graph profile: ${error}`)
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to ba able to save the property `displayName` as `string | null`?

Comment: What happens if you assign the `displayName` `null` in `defaultState`?

Comment: Tried that, it throws `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'null'`

Comment: Let's chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219591/public-room-3665)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue lies with implicit types.

```
const state = reactive(defaultState())
```

`State` here is defined without an explicit type and assigned as `reactive(defaultState)`. Meaning that it is typesafed as `defaultState`.

```
const defaultState = () => {
  return {
    profile: {
      id: '',
      displayName: '',
      givenName: '',
      surName: '',
    },
  }
}
```

`defaultState` here has no type and therefore has the implicit type of the returned object.

### So when we assign a value to `state`

```
state.profile = { ...defaultState().profile, ...response.data }
```

Where `response.data` is typesafed to `MicrosoftGraph.User` where `displayName: string | null`.

So `state.profile.displayName`'s type is `string` but, `response.data.displayName`'s type is `string | null` thus resulting in our TS error.

### The solution

All we have to do is better typesafe `defaultState`.

```
const defaultState = () => {
  return {
    profile: {
      id: '',
      displayName: '',
      givenName: '',
      surName: '',
    },
  } as { profile: MicrosoftGraph.User },
}
```