# angular Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app I have an issue with the response of an API call:

```
 private async getActor(actor:string) {
    const response = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
    let actPics = []    
      for (var val of (response as any[]).value) {
        actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)}                   
  }
```

My app runs fine but I have this message in the console when I run `ng serve`

> Error:
> src/app/quiz-editor/actor-question/actor-question.component.ts:55:41 -
> error TS2551: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'any[]'. Did you
> mean 'values'?
>
> 55     for (var val of (response as any[]).value) {
> ~~~~~
>
> node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:75:5
> 75     values(): IterableIterator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'values' is declared here.

When I `console.log(response)` I get:

[image: console.log(response)]

I did some research and I read that I should declare `response` but how should I do it?.

I've tried this solution:

```
private async getActor(actor:string) {
    const response: { value:any[] } = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
    let actPics = []      
    for (let val of response.value) {
      actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)}
}
```

But now I have this error:

```
 Error: src/app/quiz-editor/actor-question/actor-question.component.ts:55:11 - error TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'value' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type '{ value: any[]; }'.

55     const response: { value:any[] } = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
             ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/quiz-editor/actor-question/actor-question.component.ts:55:23
    55     const response: { value:any[] } = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
                             ~~~~~
    'value' is declared here.
```

Comment: you need to add typings to `response`

Comment: Same way you declare anything else `const response: { value: any[] } = ...` or whatever. See [Type definition in object literal in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787781/215552)

Comment: What's the signature of `searchActor.getActorImage`? It conflicts with the response-type suggested by @tilo

Comment: This doesn't seem correct 
`for (var val of (response as any[]).value) `. the Array type doesn't have a `value` property, are you sure you didn't make a mistake here

Comment: Change the line `for (var val of (response as any[]).value) {` to `for (var val of (response as any).value) {`

Comment: What about just : `const response: any = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()` ?

Answer (score 1):

As your log statement shows, your `response` is an object containing `value` as a key. As such, you can do the following:

```
const response: { value: any[] } = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise();
let actPics = [];
for (let val of response.value) {
  actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl);                   
}
```

Comment: Well, you could either add a typing to your service (e.g., `this.http.get<any>('__url__')`), or use the bracket notation (`response['value']` + remove declaration of response) to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell typescript what type your array is. By saying `response as any[]` the compiler does not know which objects your array contains. It may work at runtime, because typescript then "finds" the requested property.
So what you should do, is create a class/interface to define the object, that you expect to receive from your API and then parse the response to it.

Example:

```
private async getActor(actor:string) {
const response = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise();
const images = response as actorImage[];
let actPics = [];    
  for (var val of images) {
    actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)}
```

}

```
interface actorImage{
  thumbnailUrl: string   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `response` as an array of type `any`, which is incorrect. `response` is not an array, `response.value` is an array. The `any` keyword tells typescript to not bother with type checking. From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> In some situations, not all type information is available or its declaration would take an inappropriate amount of effort. These may occur for values from code that has been written without TypeScript or a 3rd party library. In these cases, we might want to opt-out of type checking. To do so, we label these values with the any type

So, the quick and dirty fix is to tell typescript that `response` is of type `any` doing something like this:

```
 private async getActor(actor:string) {
    const response = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
    let actPics = []    
      for (var val of (response as any).value) {
        actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)}                   
  }
```

Another perhaps more Angular-correct way of doing things would be to create a model and use that as your type. Here's a stripped-down model:

```
export class ImageSearchResult {
    // you could/should type this as well instead of being an array of 
    // type any. It might be something like value: []ImageData;
    value: []any; 
}
```

Then, you use your model type instead of any:

```
 private async getActor(actor:string) {
    const response = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
    let actPics = []    
      for (var val of (response as ImageSearchResult).value) {
        actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)}                   
  }
```

But going even further, your service should return the correct type. It's not the job of modules that consume services to type the data returned by services. Also - I am assuming you are returning an `observable`. Why call `toPromise`? Let's create a service function that uses Angular's http service and returns an observable of the correct type. You probably have something like this already:

```
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * Search for images by actor. Returns an observable of type ImageSearchResult.
   * @param actor The name of the actor you want to search
   */
  getActorImage(actor: string): Observable<ImageSearchResult> {
    // Refactor to appropriate http action type (post/push/etc) and url.
    return this.http.get<ImageSearchResult>(`https://my-api.com/actor-search?q=${actor}`);
  }
```

Then to consume this service function:

```
private getActor(actor:string) {
  this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).subscribe(response => {
    let actPics = []
    // No casing necessary, response is already correct type.
    for (var val of response.value) {
      actPics.push(val.thumbnailUrl)
    }
  });
}
```

Finally, it looks like you were possibly trying to use the Azure image search API. In that case, take a look at [how they type the return objects for inspiration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/d3a1e78a5209948e50d7d5e3edc594bb4a684cfd/sdk/cognitiveservices/cognitiveservices-imagesearch/src/models/index.ts#L974). Depending on your project's license, you could probably just import that project and use their models with your services.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrongfully trying to define the `response` as an array. Javascript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_properties) obviously does not have `value` property or method. You need to define the following interface instead.

```js
export interface IResponse {
  currentOffset: number;
  instrumentation: any;
  nextOffset: number;
  queryContext: any;
  readLink: string;
  totalEstimatedMatches: any;
  value: Array<any>;
  webSearchUrl: string;
  _type: string;
}
```

In an ideal case, you would also define similar interfaces for `instrumentation`, `queryContext` and `totalEstimatedMatches` as well as for the object contained in the `value` array and use them instead of using `any`.

Additionally you don't need an explicit loop to get an array of values from an object. You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead.

```js
export interface IResponse {
  currentOffset: number;
  instrumentation: any;
  nextOffset: number;
  queryContext: any;
  readLink: string;
  totalEstimatedMatches: any;
  value: Array<any>;
  webSearchUrl: string;
  _type: string;
}

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private async getActor(actor:string) {
    const response: IResponse = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise();
    let actPics: Array<string> = response.value.map(val => val['thumbnailUrl']);
  }
}
```

Further remarks:

1. Try to use the RxJS observable without converting it to a Promise. Observables provides a range of [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365955/6513921) over Promises.
2. `toPromise()` method will be [deprecated](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8.

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by the fact that you are casting the response to "any[]".
=> You hase 2 solutions:

1. you remove the casting (it is not necessary):

   private async getActor(actor:string) {
   const {value} = await this.searchActor.getActorImage(actor).toPromise()
   const actPics = value.map(val => val.thumbnailUrl)
   }
2. You declare an interface representing the type of your API response

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the type of

```
const response:{value:any[]}
```

or

```
const response:any
```

both will work