# How can I correctly type functions in object using Typescript here?

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a JS project to TS and here I have this error (using [urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql)):

`A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. ts(2355)` on line:

`playerCreate: (result, args, cache): UpdateResolver => {`

**Why?**

```
const updates = {
  Mutation: {
    playerCreate: (result, args, cache): UpdateResolver => {
      const playersQueries = cache
        .inspectFields("Query")
        .filter((x) => x.fieldName === "players");
      playersQueries.forEach(({ fieldName, arguments: variables }) =>
        cache.invalidate("Query", fieldName, variables)
      );
    },

    playerDelete: (result, args, cache, info): UpdateResolver => {
      // using result, args, cache here
    },
  },
};
```

I can see `Updateresolver` is declared like this:

```
export declare type UpdateResolver = (result: Data, args: Variables, cache: Cache, info: ResolveInfo) => void;
```

**UPDATE**:

Someone rightly told me that I'm saying that this function returns an `UpdateResolver` while the type is for the function not the return-type.

Hence the question:

**How can I correctly type here `playerCreate` and `playerDelete`**?

Comment: Figure out what you want to return (in the JS logic) in the `playerCreate` method, then return it, and then change the `UpdateResolver` type to match it. It's not clear what JS logic you want there.

Comment: TS doesn't know about `result, args, cache, info`. I wanna tell it: "that function type is `UpdateResolver`!". Only I don't know how...

Comment: @CertainPerformance seems like it's an external type `export declare type UpdateResolver = (result: Data, args: Variables, cache: Cache, info: ResolveInfo) => void;` that signature matches the method shown here, so I assume it's the method that needs to be typed as it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type definition in object literal in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript)

Comment: Nope because I'm trying to define a type for a method.

Comment: @FredHors it's a property with an arrow function assigned to it, not really a method. `{ foo: "hello" }` and `{ bar: () => {} }` are syntactically equivalent: an object with a property where you assign a value to the property. The duplicate shows how you can give such a thing a type - either type *the object* or do a type assertion. The latter is is the same as the answer you already got.

Comment: @FredHors what @VLAZ is saying regarding typing the object would be to write `const updates: {Mutation: Record<string, UpdateResolver>} = {...` and remove the types from the individual functions.  You can also write the functions outside of the object and piece it together.   `const playerCreate: UpdateResolver = (....` then `const updates = { Mutation: { playerCreate, playerDelete }, }, };`  The problem is that you can't set a property and declare the type for that property at the same time without using `as` assertion (which can be dangerous since it is an override, not a check).

Comment: Thank you @Linda Paiste. Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the code to this:

```
const updates = {
  Mutation: {
    playerCreate: (result: Data, args: Variables, cache: Cache): void => {
      const playersQueries = cache
        .inspectFields("Query")
        .filter((x) => x.fieldName === "players");
      playersQueries.forEach(({ fieldName, arguments: variables }) =>
        cache.invalidate("Query", fieldName, variables)
      );
    },

    playerDelete: (result: Data, args: Variables, cache: Cache, info: ResolveInfo): void => {
      // using result, args, cache here
    },
  },
};
```

---

EDIT: I've found out that it is actually possible by using the `as` operator:

```
const updates = {
  Mutation: {
    playerCreate: (((result, args, cache) => {
      const playersQueries = cache
        .inspectFields("Query")
        .filter((x) => x.fieldName === "players");
      playersQueries.forEach(({ fieldName, arguments: variables }) =>
        cache.invalidate("Query", fieldName, variables)
      );
    }) as UpdateResolver),

    playerDelete: (((result, args, cache, info) => {
      // using result, args, cache here
    }) as UpdateResolver),
  },
};
```

**What is the `as` operator in TypeScript?**

It tells the TypeScript compiler to think that the expression before the operator has the type after the operator. You can do some weird things with it:

```
const test = "some string" as number;
// "test" is number here!!
```

So be careful where you use it! When you apply it to functions, TypeScript will see that e. g. parameter one *should* have type `T`, so it pretends, that the function also takes a parameter of type `T`.

There is an alternative to `as`, but it cannot be used in TSX files:

```
const something = <number>"hello";
// don't do that if you don't know the actual type!
```

Of course this example is wrong, because TypeScript will think that the string is a number, but it isn't. But it shows the usage of the *type assertion*.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanna avoid: `result: Data, args: Variables, cache: Cache): void` because I can use `UpdateResolver` type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not possible. You cannot type a function after creating it.

Comment: "*But it shows the usage of the type cast.*" it shows type **assertion**. Type *casting* is different and not what `as` (or the `<>` syntax) do. Type casting is when you take a value *at runtime* and change its type *at runtime*. Since TS only operates at compile time, there is no type casting possible. In Java, for example, you can do a cast of float to integer `(int) 3.14` which will give you `3` .