# TS interface for object literal

Tags: typescript

I'm tired of writing `Record<string, any>` interface for generic objects. Hence, I got the following as a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56217448/5924738) on SO for defining the interface for objects with dynamic keys, like this

```
interface object {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

However, when I am using it, I am facing this error:

> Line 2: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'object'.

```
1| (data: object) => {
2|  if(data.errors) { 
3|    console.error(data);
4|  }
5| }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript already has an `object` type, so you can't use `object` as the name of your type. (You should be getting an error on your `interface` declaration [like I do here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPYCMBWEFmQb2QHojkBRKKVKALmQElxp4lkQ4BbFBOEEVPOhQByDNlzCAdAAoATABZZAdgCUAKGSbkAbQDWEAJ50AzmCigA5gF06vAwG41AXzXSAJnDBw6YnGBXIALwAfAQaWsAw7p5wktBUUMYBhOFaWgioIMaoADYQcZTU0V4qjmkuTvZAA).)

Just use a different name:

```typescript
interface BasicObject {
    [key: string]: any;
}
const fn = (data: BasicObject) => {
    if (data.errors) { 
        console.error(data);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM7AQeQEYBWECYyA3gFDLXIDaA1hAJ4BcyGYUoA5gLptwQTANwUAvhQQB7EB2QwQyALzIAFABM4YOG3RZchYmACUygHzkqNYDDWbtAOmhQpUDKbLIrNGtNlSAGwgnKBcoDS04Y1EfCTFRIA)

(You could also define the type as `type BasicObject = Record<string, any>;` if you liked.)

Comment: Ah man, this is stupid. What's the reason for not allowing object as the identifier?

Comment: @AakashVerma - Because TypeScript already has one. Allowing you to *redefine* it in a different way would be asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree. Can you post the link for `object` as an in-built type? I cannot find it somehow. Never seen it before too.

Comment: Thanks a ton btw. My linter didn't throw any error. What can I be missing I'm thinking.

Comment: @AakashVerma - Hmmm. Sounds like TypeScript itself isn't being run against the code? Just something that knows how to parse TypeScript? I wondered if it might be that TS didn't used to prevent you from doing this, but according to the playground even v3.3.3 did... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: Use `:any` instead of creating an interface that acts exactly like `any` would.

I know it is advised to use explicit types and to avoid `any`. But since you want the same functionality, you might as well use the widely known keyword instead of creating your own interface for that.

*Obviously, using `any` only works if you don't need other named and typed attributes on the interface, but from the question it doesn't seem like you do.*