# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, next.js

When making an axios `get` request inside a
next.js `getServerSideProps` function, I keep getting this annoying typescript underline error on map method. I have gone through all fixing possibilities but could not resolve it. The request actually works fine and pulls data, but I just need to get rid of the error. Any suggestion?

```ts
 export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {

  const { data } = await api.get("/users/index", { //axios api
    params: {
      _limit: 12
      _sort: "created_at", 
      _order: "desc"
    }
  })

  
  const users = data.map(user => { // <-error line under map method
    return {
      id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      created_at: user.created_at,
  
    }
  });
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787781/type-definition-in-object-literal-in-typescript

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w11RYw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Did you try letting get know the return type? Something like interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}


axios.get<User[]>(...)

Answer (score 6):

I think in either 0.22 or 0.23 of axios they changed the Typescript signature so now you have to cast `data` see the [changelog](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0230-october-12-2021) for more information. To resolve this you can pass a  generic:

```
type User = {
   id: string
   name: string
   created_at: string
}

const { data } = await api.get<User[]>("/users/index", { //axios api
    params: {
      _limit: 12
      _sort: "created_at", 
      _order: "desc"
    }
})
```

Else you could just typecast in situ:

```
const users = (data as User[]).map(user => { // <-error line under map method
    return {
      id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      created_at: user.created_at,
  
    }
  });
```

Comment: Solved!!! You guys are the best. It s actually the first time I am coming accross the issue, I assume it s recent change in axios/typescript documentation. Thanks so much!!